# java HTML regexp issue

Tags: java, html, regex

I am trying to transform the following string:

```
<img src="image.jpg" ... />
```

with this one

```
<img src="cid:image" ... />
```

the "image" string needs to be maintained but the string itself could be different. In the html document there are different img tags each one with a different image file.

so for instance if I have:

```
<img src="mylogo.jpg" ... />
```

it should transform to:

```
<img src="cid:mylogo" ... />
```

The images could be `jpg` or `gif`.

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Read it into an XML parser, amend it and output the result. You can use something like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: Regex is not the right tool to use for HTML parsing. Apart from that, the title talks about an issue, which issue do you have? Can you post your code please?

Comment: The issue is the absence of code to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Note:***

Apart from the fact that `Regex` is not the right tool to parse `HTML`, as mentioned in comments, because in Java there are many tools for parsing `HTML` maybe you can take a look at **[jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)** for example, I will give you a solution that fits your needs of using Regex.

**Solution:**

You can use the following Regex:

```
src=\"([\\:\\w\\s\\/]+)\\.\\w{3}\"
```

This is the code you need:

```
        String html = "<img src=\"folder1/mylogo.jpg\" ... />";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("src=\"([\\:\\w\\s\\/]+)\\.\\w{3}\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
            //This line will give you the wanted output.
            System.out.println("src=\"cid:"+matcher.group(1)+"\"");
            System.out.println("Final Result: "+html.replaceAll("src=\"([\\:\\w\\s\\/]+)\\.\\w{3}\"", "src=\"cid:$1\""));
        }
```

And this is **[a Working DEMO](https://ideone.com/dPt7Q9)**.

**Explanation:**

- `src=` matches the characters `src=` literally.
- `\"` matches the character `"` literally.
- `([\\w\\/]+)` is a capturing group to match all the wanted text.
- `\.` matches the character `.` literally.
- `\w{3,4}` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` between 3 and 4 times for extensions, *you can use `jpg|gif` instead if you are not willing to use any other image extensins.*
- `\"` matches the character `"` literally

---

## EDIT:

**Desired output:**

And to replace this expression with the wanted result just use this regex on the `replaceAll()` method with your HTML, as follow:

```
html.replaceAll("src=\"([\\:\\w\\s\\/]+)\\.\\w{3}\"", "src=\"cid:$1\"");
```

***We use `$1` to point to the first capturing group.***

Comment: Without the first and last slash, java is not javascript

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes We just need to change `\w+` with `[\\w\\/]+` .

Comment: We will add \s to the list.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: I think you should also [check your regex](https://regex101.com/r/lJ9dL5/3). You both are trying to use regex where it should not be used.

Comment: I've Edited it to include all possiblities, using `([\\:\\w\\s\\/]+)`.

Comment: @chsdk: using your code I got    'src="cid:folder1/mylogo"'   but I need the whole part '<img src='cid:folder/mylogo' ... />'

Comment: @ErnestPoldrige yes you should use this regex with `replaceAll()` method in this case, like : `html.replaceAll("src=\"([\\:\\w\\s\\/]+)\\.\\w{3}\"", "src=\"cid:$1\"")`, take a look at my EDIT.